Not able to override autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds for selenium grid using helm commands
Not able to override autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds for selenium grid using helm commands available at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/README.md
I've executed the following helm command
helm install selenium-grid --set autoscaling.enabled=true --set autoscaling.scalingType=deployment --set autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds="600" --set firefoxNode.enabled=false --set firefoxNode.deploymentEnabled=false --set edgeNode.enabled=false --set edgeNode.deploymentEnabled=false --set basicAuth.enabled=false docker-selenium/selenium-grid

Error:
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: selenium-grid/templates/chrome-node-deployment.yaml:29:4: executing "selenium-grid/templates/chrome-node-deployment.yaml" at <include "seleniumGrid.podTemplate" $podScope>: error calling include: template: selenium-grid/templates/_helpers.tpl:631:56: executing "seleniumGrid.node.terminationGracePeriodSeconds" at <gt $nodePeriod $autoscalingPeriod>: error calling gt: incompatible types for comparison```

I've tried overriding the values in the below ways
--set-string autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds=600
--set autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds=\"600\"
--set autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds=600
--set autoscaling.terminationGracePeriodSeconds="600"

